# Url Rewriting a dynamic wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am in a little trouble on wordpress, hope you can help me :)

I have a sub-page that i can call with different paramater :

- https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/showcoin/?symbol=ADA
- https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/showcoin/?symbol=ARDR

I want to make clean urls and dismiss the sub-page name :

- https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/ADA.html
- https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/ARDR.html

To do this, i tried this add_rewrite_rule :

```
function add_directory_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%symbol%", '([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^crypto-monnaies/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).html', '/crypto-monnaies/showcoin/?symbol=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_directory_rewrite' );
```

The problem is that when i call the rewrited url, it redirect me to https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/showcoin/ without the parameter

so first it should not be a 301 redirect, and second : it should carry the parameter so i can grab it in PHP.

thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks, i posted the question here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292300/url-rewriting-a-dynamic-wordpress-page